# Prove $f(x,y,z)$=$y^2$+$z^2$-$x$ is continuous

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y,z)$=$y^2$+$z^2$-$x$. I need to prove that it's continuous.

Let $x_0$=(a,b,c)$\in$$\mathbb{R}^3$ arbitrarily.
Then |$f(x,y,z)$-$f(x_0$)|

=|$y^2$+$z^2$-$x$-($b^2$+$c^2$-$a$)|

=|$y^2$+$z^2$-$x$-$b^2$-$c^2$+$a$)|

=...<$\epsilon$? I have problem finding $\delta$>0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_0$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, OK, but then you evaluate $f(x_0,x_0,x_0)$ as if $x_0$ were a scalar. That's not what you intend to do, the 3 parameters of $f$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^1$.

So let $x_0=\{a,b,c\}$, then

$$|f(x,y,z)-f(a,b,c)|=y^2+z^2-x - b^2 - c^2 + a$$
$$|f(x,y,z)-f(a,b,c)|=(y^2-b^2)+(z^2-c^2)+(a-x)$$
which you can easily upper-bound provided that $y$ is close to $b$, $z$ to $c$ and $x$ to $a$.